# Exact adjoint functors of triangulated categories

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, triangulated-categories

Let $T$ and $S$ be triangulated categories. Let $F:T\rightarrow S$ and $G:S\rightarrow T$ be two adjoint functors. Assume that one of them is exact (i.e. sends exact triangles to exact triangles and commutes with the suspension functor), then why is the other also exact?

I think I have a proof using Yoneda's lemma that if one commutes with suspensions then so does the other, but I don't know how to prove that if one sends exact triangles to exact triangles then so does the other, any help?

Comment: The argument is 5.3.6 in Neeman's triangulated categories book, which you can find on Google Books. Essentially, assuming $G$ is exact compare the image of some triangle under $F$ to the triangle in $T$ built on the image of its first morphism, and use Yoneda, five lemma, and the adjunction isomorphism to conclude.